# Cross checking of labels of two different photos

Tags: json, machine-learning, google-vision

I'm working on a project where my application needs to point out if 2 photos might be taken at the same place.

Google vision will analyze each image to a JSON file, containing the labels with the highest scores.
for example:

```
    {
  "labelAnnotations": [
    {
      "mid": "/m/0j_s4",
      "description": "metropolitan area",
      "score": 0.91176826
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/039jbq",
      "description": "urban area",
      "score": 0.8989959
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/01n32",
      "description": "city",
      "score": 0.8808476
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/0vlys",
      "description": "tower block",
      "score": 0.8789163
    }]}
```

Is there a know algorythm for cross checking the labels of two different photos, so it would give us the similarity between those photos.. using google vision?